# What can I do in order to stop .ASPXAUTH cookie from overwriting the sessions of other users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a scenario where I (User1) have logged in to my site, while i am logged in I copy the .ASPXAUTH cookie and set the cookie for some other logged in user say User2.Then the cookie restores the session of User1 in User2. This happens even if the User1 is logged out after copying the cookie or the users are on two different browsers. What can I do in order to stop this .ASPXAUTH cookie from overwriting or hijacking the sessions.